# Can´t add products to CodeIgniter Cart

Tags: codeigniter, session, cart

please, could you help me with adding products to the CI cart?

I have this function to add cart item: http://pastebin.com/QVTfa8WS

```
/**
 * add product to the cart
 */
public function add_product_to_cart()
{ 
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('qty', 'Quantity', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        redirect($this->input->post('redirect_to'));
    }
    else {
        $product = $this->products_model->get_product($this->input->post('product_id')); 

        $data = array(
            'id' => $product['id'],
            'qty' => $this->input->post('qty'),
            'price'   => $product['price'],
            'name'    => $product['title']
        ); 

        $row_id = $this->cart->insert($data);
        redirect($this->input->post('redirect_to'));
    }
}
```

And like this looks mi config.php file: http://pastebin.com/TiPZ8ta7

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

But if I call function to add product, it doesn´t and I can´t find out, where the error is. Database table for sessions I have.

EDIT:
The problem was in line 197 in Cart.php. Just comment it :)

Comment: What does print_r($product) look like?

Comment: Please post the actual code into your OP.  Dumping code into a pastebin link is not acceptable.

Comment: It´s ok. If I print_r $data, which I´m saving, it´s good - http://pastebin.com/y74HFN6K

Comment: Oh, sorry Sparky. I thought, its better. So I won´t do it anymore.

Comment: Price is 0 in that link, is that correct?

Comment: Oh, thank you man! I tried to change price to not zero value and it works. So probably problem was in this. But other problem is with czech diacritics, but it I will solve by deleting czech symbols. 
But, why, after some time it automatically clears cart and create new session row in database? How to solve this?

Comment: Well the cart is saved in sessions so it's only active while the session is active.  Not sure specifically what time frame you mean by "after some time"

Comment: After some time is something about 5 minutes. Maybe it is connected with sess_time_to_update in config.php, but if it is updating, shouldn´t it save the cart datas...?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments it appears that the issue is that price = 0 was causing a problem.  However, as [noted here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/152) this should have been resolved as of a couple of years ago.

Comment: It looks like strange. If I´m trying to save product with 0 price, it doesn´t works but if price is > 0, it works. So... maybe, they created "the error" again? :D

Comment: @JanKožušník, does it matter if the zero is passed as a string, `"0"`?  I'm thinking the `0` is being interpreted as a boolean false.

Comment: @Sparky, interesting idea, but no, if I do smth like this:
`($product['price'] == 0 ? '0' : $product['price'])` it still doesn´t works

Comment: @JanKožušník, what about `strval($product['price'])` ?

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter is this?

Comment: So problem with price is solved. I needed to comment the line 197 in Cart.php